# Unknow column on mysqli->query result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code is:

```
if (($handle = fopen(self::UPLOAD_PATH . $this->_filename, "r")) !== false) {
$mysqlCols = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {

        if ($row == 0) {
            if (md5($data[$c]) == 'c7393c74ae43e690f8bbb78fcc4d9223') {
                $data[$c] = 'Unique ID'; // Fix due to an issue with wrong characters while reading...
            }
            $mysqlCols[$c] = $data[$c];
        } else {
            $mysqlValues[$c] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data[$c]);
        }
    }

    if ($row > 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `temporary_datas` (`" . implode('`, `', $mysqlCols) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $mysqlValues) . "')";
        echo $query . ';<br>';
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
        var_dump($result);
    }

    $row++;

    if ($count++ == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

My table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `temporary_datas` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Unique ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Conversion Date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Last Updated` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Click Date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Affiliate ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Affiliate Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Advertiser ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Advertiser Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Offer ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Offer Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Creative` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Sub ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Sub ID 2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Sub ID 3` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Sub ID 4` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Sub ID 5` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Paid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Price Paid Currency` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Received` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Price Received Currency` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Reached Step` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Pixel` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Throttled` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Returned` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Test` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Transaction ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `IP Address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Click IP Address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Country` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Conversion Referrer` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Referrer` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Conversion User Agent` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Click User Agent` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Note` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Approved` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Disposition` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Region` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Language` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Provider Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Device` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Operating System` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `OS (Major Version)` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `OS (Minor Version)` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Browser` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Browser (Major Version)` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Browser (Minor Version)` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Conversion Score` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Paid Unbilled` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Received Unbilled` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Click Request Session ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Event Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Price Format` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
```

My result is (the var_dump one):

```
INSERT INTO `temporary_datas` (`Unique ID`, `Conversion Date`, `Last Updated`, `Click Date`, `Affiliate ID`, `Affiliate Name`, `Advertiser ID`, `Advertiser Name`, `Offer ID`, `Offer Name`, `Creative`, `Sub ID`, `Sub ID 2`, `Sub ID 3`, `Sub ID 4`, `Sub ID 5`, `Type`, `Paid`, `Price Paid Currency`, `Received`, `Price Received Currency`, `Reached Step`, `Pixel`, `Throttled`, `Returned`, `Test`, `Transaction ID`, `IP Address`, `Click IP Address`, `Country`, `Conversion Referrer`, `Referrer`, `Conversion User Agent`, `Click User Agent`, `Note`, `Approved`, `Disposition`, `Region`, `Language`, `Provider Name`, `Device`, `Operating System`, `OS (Major Version)`, `OS (Minor Version)`, `Browser`, `Browser (Major Version)`, `Browser (Minor Version)`, `Conversion Score`, `Paid Unbilled`, `Received Unbilled`, `Click Request Session ID`, `Event Name`, `Price Format`) VALUES ('1258806', '02/01/2014 2:40:05 PM', '02/01/2014 2:46:22 PM', '02/01/2014 2:28:44 PM', '120958', 'iTap Ads', '163', 'Zinq Media', '3002', '[WAP] Android Clean-up - ES', '37670', '', 'cU2U3A68JPK94J990MAK5QFRKD', '{gclid}', '849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c', '', 'Click', '10.7000', 'USD', '13.3800', 'USD', '1', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', '', '95.138.134.110', '46.222.188.248', 'ES', '', 'http://droid-safety.com/sp/scan1/?voluumdata=vid..00000305-cc9e-4715-8000-000000000000__vpid..0c977800-8b73-11e3-8759-c26a9a686c33__caid..c1c24ba3-cbe3-470d-9e8f-192a66242968__lid..849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c__oid1..1ac7589d-b050-4ec2-8e03-3cf386', 'CAKE: (getcake.com): Tracking Service', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ka-ge; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36', '', 'False', '', 'Madrid', 'GEORGIAN', 'xfera moviles s.a.', '', 'Android', '4', '4.3', 'Chrome', 'Other', '', '0.00', '0.0000', '13.3800', '29699629', '', 'CPA\r');
```

> Unknown column 'Price Format' in 'field list'

If I take this query and run it directly through mysql, it works fine. I don't understand what's wrong. Any ideas?

---

```
int 53
int 53
array (size=53)  0 => string 'Unique ID' (length=9)  1 => string 'Conversion Date' (length=15)  2 => string 'Last Updated' (length=12)  3 => string 'Click Date' (length=10)  4 => string 'Affiliate ID' (length=12)  5 => string 'Affiliate Name' (length=14)  6 => string 'Advertiser ID' (length=13)  7 => string 'Advertiser Name' (length=15)  8 => string 'Offer ID' (length=8)  9 => string 'Offer Name' (length=10)  10 => string 'Creative' (length=8)  11 => string 'Sub ID' (length=6)  12 => string 'Sub ID 2' (length=8)  13 => string 'Sub ID 3' (length=8)  14 => string 'Sub ID 4' (length=8)  15 => string 'Sub ID 5' (length=8)  16 => string 'Type' (length=4)  17 => string 'Paid' (length=4)  18 => string 'Price Paid Currency' (length=19)  19 => string 'Received' (length=8)  20 => string 'Price Received Currency' (length=23)  21 => string 'Reached Step' (length=12)  22 => string 'Pixel' (length=5)  23 => string 'Throttled' (length=9)  24 => string 'Returned' (length=8)  25 => string 'Test' (length=4)  26 => string 'Transaction ID' (length=14)  27 => string 'IP Address' (length=10)  28 => string 'Click IP Address' (length=16)  29 => string 'Country' (length=7)  30 => string 'Conversion Referrer' (length=19)  31 => string 'Referrer' (length=8)  32 => string 'Conversion User Agent' (length=21)  33 => string 'Click User Agent' (length=16)  34 => string 'Note' (length=4)  35 => string 'Approved' (length=8)  36 => string 'Disposition' (length=11)  37 => string 'Region' (length=6)  38 => string 'Language' (length=8)  39 => string 'Provider Name' (length=13)  40 => string 'Device' (length=6)  41 => string 'Operating System' (length=16)  42 => string 'OS (Major Version)' (length=18)  43 => string 'OS (Minor Version)' (length=18)  44 => string 'Browser' (length=7)  45 => string 'Browser (Major Version)' (length=23)  46 => string 'Browser (Minor Version)' (length=23)  47 => string 'Conversion Score' (length=16)  48 => string 'Paid Unbilled' (length=13)  49 => string 'Received Unbilled' (length=17)  50 => string 'Click Request Session ID' (length=24)  51 => string 'Event Name' (length=10)  52 => string 'Price Format
' (length=13)
array (size=53)  0 => string '1258806' (length=7)  1 => string '02/01/2014 2:40:05 PM' (length=21)  2 => string '02/01/2014 2:46:22 PM' (length=21)  3 => string '02/01/2014 2:28:44 PM' (length=21)  4 => string '120958' (length=6)  5 => string 'iTap Ads' (length=8)  6 => string '163' (length=3)  7 => string 'Zinq Media' (length=10)  8 => string '3002' (length=4)  9 => string '[WAP] Android Clean-up - ES' (length=27)  10 => string '37670' (length=5)  11 => string '' (length=0)  12 => string 'cU2U3A68JPK94J990MAK5QFRKD' (length=26)  13 => string '{gclid}' (length=7)  14 => string '849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c' (length=36)  15 => string '' (length=0)  16 => string 'Click' (length=5)  17 => string '10.7000' (length=7)  18 => string 'USD' (length=3)  19 => string '13.3800' (length=7)  20 => string 'USD' (length=3)  21 => string '1' (length=1)  22 => string 'True' (length=4)  23 => string 'False' (length=5)  24 => string 'False' (length=5)  25 => string 'False' (length=5)  26 => string '' (length=0)  27 => string '95.138.134.110' (length=14)  28 => string '46.222.188.248' (length=14)  29 => string 'ES' (length=2)  30 => string '' (length=0)  31 => string 'http://droid-safety.com/sp/scan1/?voluumdata=vid..00000305-cc9e-4715-8000-000000000000__vpid..0c977800-8b73-11e3-8759-c26a9a686c33__caid..c1c24ba3-cbe3-470d-9e8f-192a66242968__lid..849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c__oid1..1ac7589d-b050-4ec2-8e03-3cf386' (length=255)  32 => string 'CAKE: (getcake.com): Tracking Service' (length=37)  33 => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ka-ge; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36' (length=162)  34 => string '' (length=0)  35 => string 'False' (length=5)  36 => string '' (length=0)  37 => string 'Madrid' (length=6)  38 => string 'GEORGIAN' (length=8)  39 => string 'xfera moviles s.a.' (length=18)  40 => string '' (length=0)  41 => string 'Android' (length=7)  42 => string '4' (length=1)  43 => string '4.3' (length=3)  44 => string 'Chrome' (length=6)  45 => string 'Other' (length=5)  46 => string '' (length=0)  47 => string '0.00' (length=4)  48 => string '0.0000' (length=6)  49 => string '13.3800' (length=7)  50 => string '29699629' (length=8)  51 => string '' (length=0)  52 => string 'CPA\r' (length=5)
INSERT INTO `temporary_datas` (`Unique ID`, `Conversion Date`, `Last Updated`, `Click Date`, `Affiliate ID`, `Affiliate Name`, `Advertiser ID`, `Advertiser Name`, `Offer ID`, `Offer Name`, `Creative`, `Sub ID`, `Sub ID 2`, `Sub ID 3`, `Sub ID 4`, `Sub ID 5`, `Type`, `Paid`, `Price Paid Currency`, `Received`, `Price Received Currency`, `Reached Step`, `Pixel`, `Throttled`, `Returned`, `Test`, `Transaction ID`, `IP Address`, `Click IP Address`, `Country`, `Conversion Referrer`, `Referrer`, `Conversion User Agent`, `Click User Agent`, `Note`, `Approved`, `Disposition`, `Region`, `Language`, `Provider Name`, `Device`, `Operating System`, `OS (Major Version)`, `OS (Minor Version)`, `Browser`, `Browser (Major Version)`, `Browser (Minor Version)`, `Conversion Score`, `Paid Unbilled`, `Received Unbilled`, `Click Request Session ID`, `Event Name`, `Price Format`) VALUES ('1258806', '02/01/2014 2:40:05 PM', '02/01/2014 2:46:22 PM', '02/01/2014 2:28:44 PM', '120958', 'iTap Ads', '163', 'Zinq Media', '3002', '[WAP] Android Clean-up - ES', '37670', '', 'cU2U3A68JPK94J990MAK5QFRKD', '{gclid}', '849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c', '', 'Click', '10.7000', 'USD', '13.3800', 'USD', '1', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', '', '95.138.134.110', '46.222.188.248', 'ES', '', 'http://droid-safety.com/sp/scan1/?voluumdata=vid..00000305-cc9e-4715-8000-000000000000__vpid..0c977800-8b73-11e3-8759-c26a9a686c33__caid..c1c24ba3-cbe3-470d-9e8f-192a66242968__lid..849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c__oid1..1ac7589d-b050-4ec2-8e03-3cf386', 'CAKE: (getcake.com): Tracking Service', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ka-ge; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36', '', 'False', '', 'Madrid', 'GEORGIAN', 'xfera moviles s.a.', '', 'Android', '4', '4.3', 'Chrome', 'Other', '', '0.00', '0.0000', '13.3800', '29699629', '', 'CPA\r');
Unknown column 'Price Format' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Is the PHP looking at the same database as your direct MySQL connection? Stranger things have happened, it's possible that one is looking at a copy or a different server.

Comment: WHY would you put spaces and punctuation in a database field name??? Anyway, this is getting the column names from a text file; is it possible there is a bad character in the file? Is there a need to get column names from the file, or could they be fixed?

Comment: @Andrew no it's ok because when I do SELECT, it works fine.

Comment: @miken32 I've fixed the names with removing spaces and specials characters but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Post a few lines of the input file perhaps? Also the code where your database connection is initiated.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yuru3mqp

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0iMQgsHT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be issue with spaces.

- check that you dont have space when you select column

  ```
   `Price Format `
                ^----//space here
  ```

check [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb903/6)

- check in your table that the column not have spaces before or after column.

  ```
  $query = "INSERT INTO `temporary_datas` (`" . implode('`, `', $mysqlCols) . "`)
          VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $mysqlValues) . "') ";
  ```

add this

```
  $data[$c] = trim($data[$c], " \r");
```

Comment: I've checked again and recreate the structure again to be sure but it don't fix the issue: http://pastebin.com/niHmi4Jd

Comment: try this query i made.

Comment: Well, it's worth I guess with this extra quotes. I've tried but it fails. http://pastebin.com/Ff45zVUs

Comment: You was the most near from the solution. I had to add this: $data[$c] = trim($data[$c], " \r");

Answer (score 0):

Without going through the whole thing, a quick suggestion would be try without the "\r" in the final value of "CPA\r", as in PHP it is the escape sequence for carriage return and could be causing the problem.

EDIT: I think it's that the contents includes:

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ka-ge; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36'
```

- and so it is splitting at the comma:

```
" 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ka-ge; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML"
" like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36'"
```

So you would need to specify the field enclosure character for fgetcsv(). E.g.

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'")
```

You would probably need to add back the single quotes when inserting into the SQL $query.

EDIT 2:
Try debugging with this:

```
/*
if (($handle = fopen(self::UPLOAD_PATH . $this->_filename, "r")) !== false) {
$mysqlCols = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {

        if ($row == 0) {
            if (md5($data[$c]) == 'c7393c74ae43e690f8bbb78fcc4d9223') {
                $data[$c] = 'Unique ID'; // Fix due to an issue with wrong characters while reading...
            }
            $mysqlCols[$c] = $data[$c];
        } else {
            $mysqlValues[$c] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data[$c]);
        }
    }

    if ($row > 0) {*/
        #$query = "INSERT INTO `temporary_datas` (`" . implode('`, `', $mysqlCols) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $mysqlValues) . "')";
        $query = "INSERT INTO `temporary_datas` (`Unique ID`, `Conversion Date`, `Last Updated`, `Click Date`, `Affiliate ID`, `Affiliate Name`, `Advertiser ID`, `Advertiser Name`, `Offer ID`, `Offer Name`, `Creative`, `Sub ID`, `Sub ID 2`, `Sub ID 3`, `Sub ID 4`, `Sub ID 5`, `Type`, `Paid`, `Price Paid Currency`, `Received`, `Price Received Currency`, `Reached Step`, `Pixel`, `Throttled`, `Returned`, `Test`, `Transaction ID`, `IP Address`, `Click IP Address`, `Country`, `Conversion Referrer`, `Referrer`, `Conversion User Agent`, `Click User Agent`, `Note`, `Approved`, `Disposition`, `Region`, `Language`, `Provider Name`, `Device`, `Operating System`, `OS (Major Version)`, `OS (Minor Version)`, `Browser`, `Browser (Major Version)`, `Browser (Minor Version)`, `Conversion Score`, `Paid Unbilled`, `Received Unbilled`, `Click Request Session ID`, `Event Name`, `Price Format`) VALUES ('1258806', '02/01/2014 2:40:05 PM', '02/01/2014 2:46:22 PM', '02/01/2014 2:28:44 PM', '120958', 'iTap Ads', '163', 'Zinq Media', '3002', '[WAP] Android Clean-up - ES', '37670', '', 'cU2U3A68JPK94J990MAK5QFRKD', '{gclid}', '849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c', '', 'Click', '10.7000', 'USD', '13.3800', 'USD', '1', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', '', '95.138.134.110', '46.222.188.248', 'ES', '', 'http://droid-safety.com/sp/scan1/?voluumdata=vid..00000305-cc9e-4715-8000-000000000000__vpid..0c977800-8b73-11e3-8759-c26a9a686c33__caid..c1c24ba3-cbe3-470d-9e8f-192a66242968__lid..849d37fa-1c14-466e-87c1-2325c23d073c__oid1..1ac7589d-b050-4ec2-8e03-3cf386', 'CAKE: (getcake.com): Tracking Service', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ka-ge; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36', '', 'False', '', 'Madrid', 'GEORGIAN', 'xfera moviles s.a.', '', 'Android', '4', '4.3', 'Chrome', 'Other', '', '0.00', '0.0000', '13.3800', '29699629', '', 'CPA\r');";
        echo $query . ';<br>';
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
        var_dump($result);
    /*}

    $row++;

    if ($count++ == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
} else {
    return false;
}
*/
```

Comment: Not fixing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, no. The error now is: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: Are you adding back the single commas before inserting into $query?

Comment: No, without semi column

Comment: Without being able to see the output at various stages - i.e. `$mysqlCols` and `$mysqlValues` before the query is run - it is hard to debug. By the looks of it though you shouldn't need to add back the single quotes as this code is doing it: `implode("', '", $mysqlValues)`. However if your csv column data already surrounds the columns with \` then this code is wrong: `implode('\`, \`', $mysqlCols)` and needs to be `implode(', ', $mysqlCols)`.

Comment: I've put the var_dump of both variables.

Comment: Well from your results above (which it won't let me comment on) all looks ok. I've also ran this on my system and it runs fine. The only difference is I'm not doing the real_escape_string() part as I'm using PDO - which, if possible, I would suggest you use anyway.

Comment: Try this: hard-code `$query` with data you know should work - i.e. the SQL that you put directly in your database before - and see if that works. If not, then it is probably your db connection that is actually at fault.

Comment: I've tried with replacing the values by '-' and it's the same... Rahh I'm becoming crazy. I've also tried to rename the columns without spaces and soft brackets... notghing works.

Comment: I thinks it's because I have an ID column in my table. I will try something.

Comment: ID being missing shouldn't matter as your using named columns in your query.

Comment: I need to go now but have edited my post above to include code to debug. If that doesn't work then it must be a problem with you db connection. If it's ok then you will need to debug step by step.

Comment: I've tried with writing the query directly like you did. With this it works fine. But I did copy paste of the two line (the generated one and hardcoded one) and I see no differences... This is really interesting: http://pastebin.com/if9nwQat

Comment: That is weird as the results do look the same. Well without sitting down and debugging it step-by-step I can't be of much more help I'm afraid.
You could try changing the order of the columns in your db and see if the error message changes.

Comment: Yep I'm agree... I will investigate later with a 'fresh brain' lol... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fixed with adding $data[$c] = trim($data[$c], " \r"); ... Withtout that it was going to the line during my query and it was failing...

Comment: I missed that in your original post, and your later dumps of your results didn't show it. Well at least you've fixed it now.